# Where can I find out more about the Tlacique?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Okay, recently I was asked to join in on a Old World of Darkness game. I picked out a race that I was told about that sounded quite interesting. The only problem is that no one really knows anything about them, or a book that I can find anything out about them either. Does anyone know a book that there in or anything that I can point me in a direction more than, "Oh they're cool!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only *good* place to find information on the Tlacique (that is, more than just a brief mention) is in the [revised Followers of Set Clanbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588462048).

More specifics on their special type of sorcery can be found in the [Blood Sacrifice: Thaumaturgy companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588462226).

Essentially, the clanbook has all the lore and game information for the bloodline, while the thaumaturgy book focuses on fleshing out their special magic.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe i can get soomewhere with this now! lol

Comment: In V20 there's a brief description of the Tlacique. It's less than half a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a little of info in the WoD wikis:

http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Tlacique

http://wiki.white-wolf.com/worldofdarkness/index.php?title=Tlacique

But to understand what Tlacique are, you you should read the basic description of the Followers of Set, since they are a bloodline that split from them.